# Difference between SQLITE VS SQL

Tags: sqlite

Can I know please the difference between SQL Server and SQLITE .Is there any major differnces in the syntex? I know SQL but I did not learn SQLITE which I have to know within days ???

Answer (score 0):

SQLite supports pretty much full SQL syntax, in fact it probably has less quirks than MS SQL Server

The *huge* difference is that one is a server (SQL server). The other is embedded (SQLite), a totally different use case

Write a `hello world` program using SQLIte, create a table and store a row.

There are some very good free sqlite tools for inspecting a sqlite DB so you can see if your test worked

Answer (score 0):

SQL is the query language to manage databases.

SQL Server is DBMS product of Microsoft.

SQLite is a open-source DBMS often used in PoC (proof of concept, or prototypes) applications or mobile apps. Its "advantage" is that the whole database is stored in a single file in your file system. You don't have to setup a whole database server to work with sqlite. This is obviously not a solution to real life applications or web sites.